# angular sticky notes app not working

Tags: angularjs

1) The following Sticky Notes app is running perfectly under angular v1.0.0 
http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/VJ94U/

but does not run properly( I can't delete a note) under angular v1.4.7 
http://jsfiddle.net/nnkcz4ko/

may I know why?

2) This is another problem(not related to the first one):
http://plnkr.co/edit/d3EwL2Jfzcpe84y01pLi?p=preview

in this app I could not figure out from where did the `selected` property come into existence in the statement `ng-show="selected"` in file `my-pane.html`. I can't see a `$scope.selected` defined anywhere in the code.

PS: I'm fairly new to angular, so a beginner-friendly answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: angular creates those variables on the fly on $scope

Comment: on 1) if you change the 'ng-click' to `ng-click="deleteNote(note.id)"` it works to delete

Comment: You'd better try to focus a question on just one problem, answering two questions in one place could just cause confusion.

Comment: Sorry @entre but as far as I have learnt, I should access the selected property using $scope and not directly, since I did not bind any selected property to the scope variable myself.

Comment: @Himanshu thats not what i mean. you can access properties the way you want, it was answer to your question 2...

Comment: @klskl thanks!, yet another discovery... now the delete is working but I want to know that why did the original code failed to function as expected. Since I had only changed the angular version, I think the answer is more closely related to the changes in versions of angular, but I failed to recognize what changes are resposible for it.

Comment: @entre but I did not assign any `selected` property to the scope, the `selected` property is attached to `$scope.panes[0]` and the other items of the array, so how did the code access it directly?

Comment: @imbalind thanks for your suggestion, you are right I'll be careful the next time. (I'm not modifying the question because this question has already got comments for both the questions)

Comment: @entre okay, I understood what you were saying. I agree with you that the `$scope.selected` property will be created on the fly, but the default value will be `false` so both the `panes` are not visible. But when the app runs, the hello pane gets displayed. I just want to know where in the code does the visibility of the panes  is determined.(i.e. `$scope.selected` is set to `true`)

Answer (score 0):

okay, I figured out that in problem 2) the selected property is set directly on the **isolated** scope, so it can be accessed directly from that scope(i.e. from inside the my-pane directive).